# Undelete action on a comment even though it wasn't deleted

Tags: bug, comments, moderator-tools

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/users/:userIdHere/post-comments

For example, [this comment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1096427/sfml%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F/1096441#comment1890222_1096441). It's not deleted. But in the admin panel, when I pick this comment, there is an "Undelete" option.

> [image: screenshot showing an undeleted comment selected via a checkbox, with a dropdown option for "undelete" able to be selected]